# chmod not causing changes

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

This seems like a fairly simple problem to me but I can't figure out what exactly the problem is. I have a .pem file that I am trying to change the permissions of so that I can use it to secure copy to my server. I need to change the permissions from 777, as they are now, to 600, for scp to work. I enter:

```
    chmod -v 600 fileName.pem
```

The output of this is:

```
mode of 'fileName.pem' changed from 0777 (rwxrwxrwx) to 0600 (rw-------)
```

Great. Now I look at the file permissions:

```
ls -l
```

And get the output:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1692 Jan 00 00:00 fileName.pem
```

Why can't I change these permissions? I've tried *sudo chmod ...* without success as well.

Comment: Do you check permissions *before* sending `fileName.pem` to the remote system?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Are you asking whether or not I do the _ls -l_ before doing the _scp_?

Comment: Yes. I thought that maybe settings of `umask` at the remote system or some other directory settings cause permissions to reset to the defaults

Comment: Interesting... When I try it without the _ls -l_ it still doesn't work but it appears to have lost the error message that this _chmod_ was looking to solve.

Comment: Is this file on a disc with a file system that doesn't support Linux permissions, eg NTFS?

Comment: Ah geez I didn't think it was but I just double checked and it is.